# How i read resources file for stream

Tags: c#

I need to stream, but I am getting the error "_stream  is null". I want to read a resources file.

- my project name is  "WindowsFormsApplication1"
- my file name is  "resources.resx"
- my file name is "myReportCustemer.repx"

  ```
  Stream _stream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.myReportCustemer.repx");

  my_XtraReport1.LoadLayout(_stream);
  ```

Visual Studio shows me "_stream is null"

edit:

I trying to embed devexpress report file in my resources. that's why .repx

I guest my problem is add to file resources. becouse if I embed image... I can see in my resource folder but myReportCustemer.repx file no exist in resource file..

Comment: Shouldn't the `.repx` be `.resx`?

Comment: Mark the file as EmbeddedResource

Comment: What is type of my_XtraReport1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @walther No I'm pretty sure it's a DevExpress XtraReport, which has a .repx extension. However, OP you have spelled "myReportCustemer" wrong - don't know if this is your issue?

Comment: when your breakpoint is set, try this in your Immediate Window: `_assembly.GetManifestresourceNames ()`. So you'll know if the resource is there, and what's its name.

Comment: It is guaranteed to be the wrong name, it will never have "Properties" in the name.  If you don't know the real name then run ildasm.exe on your compiled EXE.  You'll see the .mresource in the manifest.